# How component can remove/delete itself from DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a following JSX code:

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var Items = this.props.data.map(function(item) {
      return (
        <Item key={item.id}>
          {item.text}
        </Item>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="items">
        {Items}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Item = React.createClass({
  handleDelete: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Delete this (only this) component completely (remove it from DOM).
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="item">
          {this.props.children}
          <button className="delete" onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <List data={Array of items} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

My question is: how items can completely remove/delete themselves in their own handleDelete() function?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Do you just want to delete the node from DOM, or is it backed by some data that is changing? In _both_ cases you should be providing a callback from the parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution would be to have the container component (ie `List`) handle the `onDelete` functionality, and then update its state (keep track of deleted items). Then in your `List`'s `render()` function, you can filter out any deleted items:

```
var List = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { deleted: [] };
  },

  onDelete: function (id) {
    this.setState({ deleted: this.state.deleted.concat([id]) });
  },

  render: function() {
    var Items = this.props.data
      .filter(item => this.state.deleted.indexOf(item.id) === -1)
      .map(item => {
        return (
          <Item key={item.id} id={item.id} onDelete={id => this.onDelete(id)}>
            {item.text}
          </Item>
        );
      });

    return (
      <div className="items">
        {Items}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Item = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="item">
          {this.props.children}
          <button className="delete" onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <List data={Array of items} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Your solution is robust, but in most cases we can do two things to make it a bit simpler, without breaking the code: (1) Instead of keeping a list of deleted entries, you can just remove deleted entries from the map. Then you don't have to do the filtering afterwards. (2) Instead of`.map(item =>` you may do `.map((item, index) =>` to get the index of the item in the map. Then you can use that index to remove from the map.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to delete it from the child component itself then you may try this:

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode);
```

but its always better for parent to manipulate the child components rather than child components modifying itself. So, you should put the logic inside your parent component to mount the required number of child components, and child should only communicate to parent.

> **EDIT**

i do not recommend to use the above method for the asked question, i wrote this answer because this is one of the way to unmount your component. Here is the [official doc.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode) Its completely fine to use this method, when you want to remove some child components from parent component that's why ReactDOM allows us to use this function.

Comment: Echoing Sergio: need explanation from @JeffC.
IMO this answer is perfectly valid & adheres to recommendations laid out in ReactDOM.

Comment: Because you should avoid manipulating the DOM directly whenever possible; this also wouldn't work when the data is fetched from a database/rendered dynamically in another way